# Can you use Objective-C categories to clean up backwards compatibility with older SDKs?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, categories, backwards-compatibility

There are 2 main considerations to take into account when thinking about backward compatibility :

- build target
- current SDK for compilation

If I compile with iOS SDK 3.1.3, `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale` will raise an error.

To deal with this, I can write :

```
CGLoat scale = 1.0;
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 40000
scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
#endif
```

But... if my minimum version target is let's say 3.1.3, this call will crash a 3.1.3 device, even if it compiles fine.

So I must write :

```
CGFloat scale = 1.0;
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 40000
    if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
#endif
```

Saying that, I wonder if there is a way to implement

```
- (CGFloat)scale;
```

into a UIScreen category, inside which I could manage this kind of problem, and then the caller would just have to write :

```
CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

without having to think about its used SDK nor its min target.

If possible, how would you write such a category so that it compiles fine with a 3.1.3 SDK, a 4.3 SDK, and runs fine on a 3.1.3 device as on a 4.3 device?

Comment: Apple has a habit of dropping support for old versions of iOS. Odds are good they'll require a minimum of 4.0 and up very soon. I wouldn't bother with 3.1.3 support for an App Store app at this point.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan : Don't point 3.1.3 version, the problem is there and will still be there in some monthes. Is 4.2.1 a so old version to approve that its SDK is not available anymore in XCode ? If I make an app today, I NEED to make it available only for 4.3 minimum, assuming I don't want to check word by word my whole code to check its iOS availability. That's just bullshit. We should at least have a simple way to be alerted that a call is not available for a targeted iOS version, to be able to correct the code.

Comment: You do, and you've already discovered it. Perhaps you're used to C# or Java, where symbol lookup semantics are different. In Objective-C, you must use introspection to meaningfully check for the presence of methods.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan : ok, but I still don't see how I may write it. If I write a scale method, first what will happen if the scale property is already defined (working with a 4.0 SDK). I assume the method will be used instead of the property. And second, if I test respondToSelector inside it, of course it will always return YES so I can't test is my device iOS really respond to that selector without the category.

Comment: You shouldn't use the same name since it will override the existing implementation and cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do this with some method-swizzling, but I really wouldn't recommend it (gets confusing really fast).

I'd prefix your category method instead, something like `foo_scale`. This way you won't run into name conflicts and you still only have one method to call.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the pre-processor macro (nor should you use them for this sort of task — try to forget about precise iOS versions, and think more in terms of available features. This will be more flexible for you in the long run).

You could write a category method like so:

```
- (CGFloat)my_scale { // or whatever prefix you choose. you shouldn't try to mash with Apple's method names
    CGFloat scale = 1.0f;
    if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    return scale;
}
```

Do this, and make sure your `Base SDK` is set to `Latest iOS` (which will always choose the latest iOS version for whichever SDK version you have installed), and set your `Deployment Target` to `iOS 3.1.3` or the lowest version to which you want to deploy.

This combination will alleviate the need for a pre-processor macro, and it will compile and run just fine, too. This gives you more flexibility.